# XML HTTP RESPONSE ISSUE : XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, http-post, httpresponse

Following is the Java Script code i have.

```
//URL = http://dev.stage.com/restapi/vc/auth/sessions/login/
//parametersURL = user.login=******&user.password=******
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlHttp.open( "POST", URL, true );
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parametersURL.length);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlHttp.send(parametersURL);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        return xmlHttp.responseXML;
    }
}
```

When tested in IE8, i am getting the correct response in the alert box.

```
<response status="success"><value type="string">
uX-DjjZ2XrSB_GAfjSLTapOJvyvd2U9Y8MHsQzrvFeo.</value></response>
```

But when tested in Chrome and Firefox. The response is empty. When checked with FireBug the response is empty and in the XML I get the following error

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{9fc08684-36c5-42b2-
b641-e9400c6e627f} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Using Poster plugin in Firefox i can get the correct response.

Please, let me know what is the issue

Comment: Changed the title so that future user get to thus question very easily. Revert it back if you don't like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the cross domain issue. Which is not handled correctly in IE and hence it worked. Use jsonp to make cross domain requests and it worked like a charm.